# Winsock Отправить пакет клиенту

Tags: delphi

Как отправить из клиента клиенту же данные, чтобы клиент считал их функцией Recv?
Заранее прошу прощения за глупо поставленный вопрос.
Клиент и Сервер обмениваются данными, мне нужно передать данные клиенту якобы от сервера.

Comment: Отправьте данные с клиента на сервер, а сервер пусть отправит клиенту. В чем вопрос?

Comment: приложение не моё :)

Answer (score 1):

Recv читает из сокета, появляющегося после connect - по указанному адресу. 
Подменить сокет скорее всего не удастся...

Так что проще всего проксировать трафик в вашем случае по моему мнению.

Comment: Ну, предположим, что номер сокета я знаю, он хранится в определенном месте в памяти. Могу ли я в него послать? Что-нибудь вроде sendto на локалхост якобы от имени сервера